# Disappearing elements in a todo list?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a little todo app for a multi-purpose tool I'm in the process of building (as a personal project). I'm using jQuery as to keep the code concise but I've ran into a little bit of a problem; in that, when I enter text into the text box and hit the button to add it to the list, it appears as though it is working fine, however nothing appears on the screen and the text box appears as though it was empty all along by highlighting red. The code is below:

```js
$("#add-btn").on("click", function() {
  const newLi = document.createElement("li");
  const inputValue = $("#task-entry-box").val();
  const textNode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  newLi.appendChild(textNode);

  if (inputValue === "") {
    $("#task-entry-box").css("border", "1px solid red");
  } else {
    $("#task-entry-box").css("border", "");
    $("#todo-list").append(newLi);
  }
  $("#task-entry-box").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-container">

  <ul id="todo-list">

  </ul>

  <fieldset id="todo-add-form">
    <input id="task-entry-box" type="text" placeholder="What do you need to do? Get lunch, drink water etc." />
    <button id="add-btn"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
  </fieldset>

</div>
```

I'm completely baffled by this so if someone could help to explain where the heck the text that i enter into the text field is going, I'd appreciate it.

P.S. I'm currently on an iPad and won't have access to a laptop/computer for a few days so don't have access to a console to check for errors so I'm afraid I won't be able to provide any more insight to the issue!

EDIT: Added html code in.

Comment: Just deleted my answer ! Because your code is doing fine !!! If you don't see that appended text, something else is hiding it or it's CSS issue. https://jsfiddle.net/zrpctv23/

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't see your HTML, I have to guess that you're not properly selecting the elements in your jQuery.   Because the code you posted works fine.

```js
$("#add-btn").on("click", function(){
     const newLi = document.createElement("li");
     const inputValue = $("#task-entry-box").val();
     const textNode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
     newLi.appendChild(textNode);

     if(inputValue === ""){
       $("#task-entry-box").css("border", "1px solid red");
     }else{
       $("#task-entry-box").css("border", "");
       $("#todo-list").append(newLi);
     }
     $("#task-entry-box").val("");
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="task-entry-box"><button id="add-btn">
Add Task
</button>
<ul id="todo-list">

</ul>
```

Comment: It's not that I've selected any elements incorrectly; I've checked that about 100 times over the past couple of hours.

Comment: @KyleJones I didn't change anything in your JS. All I did was place the required elements in the DOM. You can see my snippet works correctly, right? So there must be something different about your HTML.  (Edit: or your CSS is hiding it as Bilel suggested.) Can you edit your question and add the HTML?

Comment: Added the html in

Comment: @KyleJones I copied your exact code into a snippet (and added jQuery) and it works just fine. If my edit gets approved, you can see for yourself. If it's not working on your page then there must be something else going on.

Comment: Yeah I see. My only guess is that it's an issue with the app that I'm using then. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @KyleJones Any time. And if you don't mind, hit that green checkmark for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
form.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {                 
    e.preventDefault() ;
}) ;
```

**Add this second line to your code. #the reason is the form reloads when submitted, so this prevents the element from disappearing when submitted**